# How to trigger Zoneminder to phone a land line

Tags: triggers, alarm, phone-call, modem, zoneminder

1. You need to connect your PC to the land-line via a "modem".
2. Install wvdial (and configure it) (and test that it rings your phone).
3. Then modify the [script supplied by zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ)  to access the modem (search that page for e.g. "trigger").
4. Run that script e.g. in your home directory.

Also I discover that modems, being rather old-fashioned, are not well supported in Linux e.g. "Winmodems" (are cheap)because they do low level stuff in (Windows) software to save on hardware hence my old-PC's PCI-modem is not supported any more in current Linux i.e. I had to find a hardware-driven modem e.g. a "Trendnet TFM 561u" instead. This worked out-of-the-box on my Mint 14 system (December 2013) appearing as /dev/ttyACM0.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use lib ("/opt/zm/share/perl/5.14.2");

use ZoneMinder;

$| = 1;

# mDbgInit( "myscript", level=>0, to_log=>0, to_syslog=>0, to_term=>1 );

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:database=".ZM_DB_NAME.";host=".ZM_DB_HOST, ZM_DB_USER, ZM_DB_PASS );

my $sql = "select M.*, max(E.Id) as LastEventId from Monitors as M left join Events as E on M.Id = E.MonitorId where M.Function != 'None' group by (M.Id)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached( $sql ) or die( "Can't prepare '$sql': ".$dbh->errstr() );

my $res = $sth->execute() or die( "Can't execute '$sql': ".$sth->errstr() );
my @monitors;
while ( my $monitor = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) 
{
    push( @monitors, $monitor );
}

while( 1 ) {
    foreach my $monitor ( @monitors ) {
        next if ( !zmMemVerify( $monitor ) );

        my $lei = eval {               # avoid...
            $monitor->{LastEventId};   # ...aborting
        };                             # ...this script
        warn $@ if $@;                 # ...if there is no
        if( ! $lei ) {                 # ...LastEventId
        next;                          # ...e.g. for a clean start
        }                              # ...after clearing out database.

        my $last_event_id = zmHasAlarmed( $monitor, $lei );


        if ( $last_event_id ) {
            if ( $monitor->{Name} ne "monitor-1" && $monitor->{Name} ne "monitor-2" )  {
                my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
                if ( $hour > 23 || $hour < 7 ) {
                    $monitor->{LastEventId} = $last_event_id;
                    print( "Monitor ".$monitor->{Name}." has alarmed \n" );
                    my $cmd .= "echo ";
                    $cmd .= "\"";
                    $cmd .= "Garage Alarm: ".$monitor->{Name};
                    $cmd .= "\"";
                    $cmd .=  ' | mail -s `curl ifconfig.me` myemailaddress@gmail.com';
                    system ($cmd);
                    system('wvdial');
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    sleep( 1 );
}
```

This is my first attempt at (modifing) Perl. It will be rough!

The first system($cmd) emails me at myemailaddress@gmail.com (you will need to set this up yourself to get mail to work) with the current URL just in case it has recently changed.

The second system('wvdial') rings my phone.

As you can see, "monitor-1" and "monitor-2" are ignored.

As you can see, it is enabled between the hours of just after 11pm to just before 7 am.

My /etc/wvdial.conf file looks similar to this:-

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = USB Modem
Phone = 123456789
ISDN = 0
Password = <Your Password>
New PPPD = yes
Username = <Your Login Name>

Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
Baud = 460800
Dial Command = ATDT
Auto Reconnect = off
Dial Attempts = 1
```

Comment: Did you post that as a tutorial for other users or do you have an actual question ?

Comment: It is two weeks of struggling condensed into a half-hour solution + explanations.

Comment: You should post your tutorial of getting this working on a blog somewhere.  Looks very interesting.